# P(B)=1 does not imply B $\ne \Omega$

Tags: probability

My teacher has given a problem and given the answer of it.

The problem was that if $P(B)=1$ does $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$

$P(B)=1$ does not imply that $B=\Omega$

$\therefore P(A\cap B)\ne P(B)$

If $\Omega=\{p,q,r\}$ st. $P(r)=0$ and let $B=\{p,q\}$

Now $B\ne \Omega$ and $P(B)=1$

Now whatever $A$ be its always true that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$.

Am I right or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are. $\ $

Comment: "Am I right or not?" Difficult to say since you are asked to prove or disprove that if $P(B)=1$ then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$ for every $A$ but you do not even touch the question except to state without justification that if $P(B)=1$ then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$ for every $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $P(B)=1$ does not imply $B=\Omega$, as your example shows. However, if $P(B)=1$, it is true that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)$ for every $A$. Here it is the proof:

On one hand, it is clear that $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ (because $A\cap B\subseteq A$). On the other hand, by additivity, $P(\Omega \setminus B)=P(\Omega)-P(B)=1-1=0$. So, we get:

$$\begin{align*}P(A)&=P(A\cap B)+P(A\setminus B)\\ &\leq P(A\cap B)+P(\Omega\setminus B)\\&=P(A\cap B)+0\\ &=P(A\cap B).\end{align*}$$

Thus, we conclude that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)$.